# How to print only 5 integers to a line from an array

Tags: java, arrays, println

I have written a program that will load an array of 50 random integers ranging between 0 and 128. I am trying to print the array, with only 5 integers printed on each line. But, I can't seem to do it.

```
public static void printList(int len, int[] list){
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.println(list[i]);
        } // end for 
} // end printList
```

I want the output to be only 5 integers to a line.

Comment: What do you mean by 'with only 5 integers printed on each line. '.                                                Does it mean that it you have 50 integers then you will have 10 lines and in each line there will be 5 numbers ?

Answer (score 3):

This may work:

```
public static void printList(int len, int[] list){
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i % 5 ==0) {
                  System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.print(list[i] + "\t");
        } // end for 
} // end printList
```

Comment: it seems `i==0` will print `\n` first.

Comment: and you need ```% 5``` for 5 integers per line!

Answer (score 2):

Reworking @AmalK's code:

```
public static void printList(int len, int[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        String sep = "\t"; // usually have a tab after each integer
        if ((i+1) % 5 == 0 || i+1 == len)
            sep = "\n"; // but periodically use a newline instead     
        System.out.print(list[i] + sep);
    } 
}
```

My changes are: 5 numbers per line; no initial newline; newline after last number even if len is not a multiple of 5; no trailing tab on line.

Answer (score 0):

This should be working fine:

```
public static void printList(int len, int[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(list[i] + " , ");
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first line will have only one number on it. The last line may not end in a newline.

Answer (score 0):

if you are certain that the array will always be having number of elements as a multiple of 5, then this can be used.

Its saving you many loop iteration.

```
public static void printList(int len, int[] list){
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i+=5) {

            System.out.println(list[i] + "\t"+ list[i+1] + "\t"+ list[i+1] +
 "\t"+ list[i+1] + "\t"+ list[i+1] + "\t");
        } // end for 
} // end printList
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with `Guava`, you can try this demo. `Guava` use `substring` of JDK to do partition, so it won't add too many memory cost.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TestDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<List<Integer>> partition = Lists.partition(list, 5);
        partition.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.stream().map(y -> Integer.toString(y)).collect(Collectors.joining(","))));
    }

}
```